# I want to add a menu breakdown

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am developing a project and I can't do the following:

**For example:** I want the `sub-tabs` to open when the cursor hovers over the `Services tab` in the menu, and when I click on any of them, I want it to open in the same window but on a new page.

Here is Reference [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUotz.png)

```js
import{ Socials } from "@/constants";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
return (
<div
    className="w-full h-[85px] fixed top-0 shadow-lg shadow-[#2A0E61]/50 bg-[#03001417] backdrop-blur-bold-md z-50 px-150">
    <div className="w-full h-full flex flex-row items-center justify-between m-auto px-[40px]">
        <a href="#about-me" className="h-auto w-[570px] flex flex-row items-right" \>
            <Image src="/speclogo.png" alt="logo" width={200} height={100}
                className="cursor-pointer hover:animate-slowspin" />

        </a>

        <div className="w-[1600px] h-full flex flex-row items-center justify-between md:mr-20">
            <div
                className="flex items-center justify-between w-full h-auto border border-[#7042f861] bg-[#0300145e] mr-[50px] px-[30px] py-[10px] rounded-full text-gray-200">
                <a href="#about-me" className="cursor-pointer">
                    Hakkımızda
                </a>
                <a href="#services" className="cursor-pointer">
                    Hizmetler
                </a>
                <a href="#solutions" className="cursor-pointer">
                    Çözümler
                </a>
                <a href="#reference" className="cursor-pointer">
                    Referanslar
                </a>
                <a href="#career" className="cursor-pointer">
                    Kariyer
                </a>
                <a href="#contacts" className="cursor-pointer">
                    Bize Ulaşın
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        { <div className="flex flex-row gap-5">
            {Socials.map((social) => (
            <Image src={social.src} alt={social.name} key={social.name} width={50} height={10} />
            ))}
        </div> }
    </div>
</div>
);
};

export default Navbar;
```

Comment: What he wants is, for example, when I come to the Services section with the cursor, 3 tabs should be arranged towards the bottom as item 1, item 2 and item 3 and they should be clickable. And for example, when I click on item 1, I want a new page to open in the same window, but I couldn't.